# How to change the following foreach code to Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

```
public class A
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int values { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<DifferentData> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DifferentData
{
    public int NewID { get; set; }
    public int Differentvalues { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I have a code like below

```
var TopAClassData = new A();
var TopBClassData = new B();
var anotherItemD = new DifferentData();

foreach (var item in TopAClassData.data)
{
    foreach (var anotherItem in TopBClassData.Data)
    {
        if (item.ID == anotherItem.NewID)
        {
            item.values = anotherItemD.Differentvalues;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set the *Differentvalues* from the *List* to *values* field of *List* if the *NewId* and *ID* are matching. Is there anyway to convert the **foreach** code to **simpler linq query**

Comment: Why do you want to use a Linq query here? Linq is really intended for querying (it's in the name!) rather than mutating.

Comment: You could change the query part (searching the intersection of the `data`/`Data` properties) so you'd only have one `foreach` to iterate over, but I don't know that that would be "simpler"; you'd just move the complexity to LINQ.

Comment: what i want to do is to avoid **multiple foreach** if possible

Comment: But why? Linq would basically be doing the same foreach loops but obfuscated inside hidden methods.

Comment: I know that functionality wise there won't be much change. but what i want is to avoid nested foreach and have fewer lines of code

Comment: Having fewer lines of code isn't necessarily better. There's only 9 lines here, a Linq statement would likely not be much less, but would introduce some really complex behaviour, and delegate, and will almost certainly be (albeit not noticeably) slower.

Comment: Also, please fix your code above, I can see about a dozen things about it that make it not even compile.

Comment: Please don't post fake classes. Post real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly nice LINQ version:

```
IEnumerable<Data> items =
    from item in TopAClassData.data
    join anotherItem in TopBClassData.Data on item.ID equals anotherItem.NewID
    select item;
    
foreach (Data item in items)
    item.values = anotherItemD.Differentvalues;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join two lists and then enumerate:

```cs
var items = TopAClassData.data
    .Join(TopBClassData.Data, x => x.ID, x => x.NewId, 
       (item, anotherItem) => item);

foreach(var item in items)
{
    item.values = anotherItemD.Differentvalues;
}
```

Comment: How si this any better than having nested foreach loops? This makes the entire thing far less readable and probably even slower to execute.

Comment: It should be at least faster. Join uses lookup dictionary to match records.

Comment: I am not so sure, but regardless, my first point still stands.

Comment: Actually I always do in that way. Enumerating second list can hit performance if it is big.